# Report generated that shows the IP addresses of customers/visitors

Tags: magento, ip

Is it possible to detect a visitor's IP address and store it on the magento administrator so that the admin can be able to view who visited their store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already possible. Take a look at `Customers->Online Customers`. This log is cleared after 15 minutes by default but you can increase the value from `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Online Customers Options`. Don't make the value too big because it may affect performance.
**EDIT** (correction)
All the access to you website is stored in the table `log_visitor_info` including the IP address. This table is not cleaned up after X minutes.

Comment: Thanks for that. basically these Ip addresses has to be stored in a database. its kind of like a log that track and keep the customers

Comment: That is what actually happens. The IP address is stored in the table `log_visitor_info` in the field `remote_addr` The only inconvenient is that is stored as a `long` number instead of the actual address. You can solve this by calling `long2ip(value)`